# Is it possible to get a facebook feed to a closed group that I belong to but do not own?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-group, facebook-feed

I know it's possible to get an rss feed or whatever for wall posts of groups. However, every time I try it with a closed group that I belong to, it doesn't work. Is this possible if you aren't the admin or owner of a group but just a member? Here are the steps that I've taken so far.

> 1. Create an application on http://developers.facebook.com/setup/
> 2. When you are done, you will see App Name, App URL, App ID, and App Secret. Copy down these data.
> 3. access https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&scope=offline_access&redirect_url={URL}.
>
> Replace {CLIENT_ID} with your App ID. Replace {URL} with your App URL.
>
> 4. When you prompt “Request for Permission” page, click [ ALLOW ] button.
> 5. You will be redirect to {URL}/?code={YOUR CODE}
> 6. Copy down {YOUR CODE}
> 7. Access https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={URL}&client_secret={APPLICATION_SECRET}&code={YOUR_CODE}
>
> Replace {CLIENT_ID} with your App ID Replace {URL} with your App URL
>   Replace {APPLICATION_SECRET} with your App Secret Replace {YOUR_CODE}
>   with your {YOUR CODE}
>
> When you hit the url, you will get access token.

At this point I don't get an access token I get this.

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "This authorization code has expired.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100
}}
```

**The problem is, I just created the auth code like 2 seconds prior. No way could it have expired.
So I can't follow the rest of the steps below until I have that access token.**

> Copy your access token.
>
> Now, access the following url with your access token.
>
> http://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR GROUP ID}/feed?access_token={ACCESS
>   TOKEN}
>
> When you go to your group page, you url is something like
>   /group.php?gid=xxxxxxxxx. In this case, gid is your group id.

Comment: Hi Owen. I am having that same problem you had. Can you please please help me? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955145/is-it-possible-to-get-facebook-feed-likes-and-comments-from-a-closed-group-that I'm very confused

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, yes you can access the posts even if you are not admin/owner. If you can see all posts of a group, there should be no reason not to be able to access them with the api.

First, check if the access token is having 'user_groups' checked, otherwise you will not be able to access a closed groups. You can play with [Graph Explorer yourself](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), till you get the needed results.

If you experience problems after you get the right access token, then check if the token is not expired.

Comment: I can't find `user_groups` option in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately this option is no longer available. :( for some reason fb removed it from the api. However, u can still access it if u choose API version 2.0 up to 2.3.

Comment: What are causes of using old API versions ? I thought theyre going to expire soon? :(

Comment: Indeed they will expire, but probably not rly soon. If i've to guess, probably with version 3 and those major updates did not happen since graph.

Comment: Looks like there's no way to get feed data from closed groups even if you're a member of the group after 6/12 2017. I had an app that worked fine but now it's broken. So facebook expects you to be the admin of a group to access the feed programmatically even if you're a member in it. Shame.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418809

Comment: @Gaurav's right, user_groups is now deprecated and I can't seem to find a way to access those closed groups, if I'm not the admin.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to v2.3 because from version 2.4 facebook restricted with closed groups and also user's new feed.

Try with v2.3 and check on read_stream on get token access. Note that only by switching to v2.3, we can see the read-stream option

https://tngotran.wordpress.com/2017/02/01/facebook-api-explain-example-and-real-project-tutorial/