# Facebook block graph api access to closed groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a program that read posts from groups by using
graph.facebook.com/v2.3/[group_id]/feed

I've heard that facebook is about to block the access for developers to closed groups.
but I can't find any formal mention of this.

Anyone know if it's true?

Thanks

Comment: Seriously? Surely as an Admin of the closed group you can still do it. Asking if hearsay is true or false isn't a coding QA suited to this site. Suggest you dig up the documentation yourself. Sorry voting to close. I've written a scanner to get stats off a closed group I am the admin of so if this is true it would be disappointing. But FB are forever locking down their API and to PR / advertising companies Facebook sells statistics.

Comment: Confused about this too - on the docs page for the group-id/feed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed) one of the permissions seems to be:

"A user access token for a member of the group."

This suggests to me if you are a member of a closed group then you don't need any special permission whitelisted for your app. But I can't get the feed items for a closed group.

Answer (score 9):

Update:

`user_groups` is gone, now we need to use `user_managed_groups` instead of `user_groups`, and the problem with this permission is, it only allows you access to the groups which are open, or the one you are admin/developer/tester of. No closed groups are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

They don´t block access, but you will not get `user_groups` approved and the permission may get removed sooner or later:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_groups

There is a new permission called `user_managed_groups`, use that one. For groups you are an admin of, nothing changes.

Comment: "you will not get user_groups approved and the permission may get removed sooner or later" - can you share a link for the source for that? And if i'm a member of such groups will it still get blocked?

Comment: i´ve included the relevant link to answer your question. not sure what you mean by "getting blocked" though.

Comment: The thing is that I use the access token only on the server side of my program, and it already has the user_groups permission so currently i'm still able to read the feed of private groups which i'm a member of. so you say facebook will remove the permission in the near future?

Comment: maybe. i believe there are rumors about that. with user_managed_groups you´re definitely on the safer side. you should not have any business getting the feed of groups you´re not an admin of.

Comment: So, if i'm a member of closed group, can i read its feeds by graph api?

Comment: Where do you guys see or change those permissions like user_managed_groups? I can't find place where I can manage it on groups I created...

Comment: you do that for testing in the api explorer, or you ask for the permission in your login process. check out the docs about how to use permission with login.

Comment: `user_managed_groups` was deprecated in version 3.0. Are there any alternatives, even for admins of the group? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook seems to remove all possibilities for users to read their own content automatically:

- No more access to [user groups](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/979251278808550) (without being admin of that group)
- No more access to [messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/thread/) (except for conversations with pages)

This will become a severe problem with deprecation of API v2.3 on [July 8, 2017](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#versions).